# Regex with an exception - don't match all things if digit is next symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi again I need a little help to create a better regex expression.
I have the following text:

```
Welcome.to-RegEx_r.v2.0.03.by.gski.v2.0.03 danner.com!bla-la_122.232-13!
```

what I need is, to remove all dots, dashes and underscores, but if there is a string like "v2.0.03" to skip removing the dots and to continue from nex char which is not from version(dot, dash, underscore, letter/char) So the string have to look like this one:

```
 Welcome to RegEx r v2.0.03 by gski v2.0.03 danner com!bla la 122 232 13!
```

I tried and almost works with this regex:

```
([\.\-\_])(?![\d])
```

but if next char after dot, dash or underscore is digit, doesn't work. here's my try in regexr - http://regexr.com/3b7qu

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: jquery

$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/([\.\-\_])(?![\d])/g, " "));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var str = 'Welcome.to-RegEx_r.v2.0.03.by.gski.v2.0.03 danner.com!bla-la_122.232-13!';

str = str.replace(/(?:(v\d+(?:\.\d+)+) *)?[._ -]+/g, "$1 ");
//=> Welcome to RegEx r v2.0.03 by gski v2.0.03 danner com!bla la 122 232 13!
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/7)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the second dot in the second " v2.0.03" is matched too :)

Comment: Where is 2nd dot being matched? Isn't the replaced string same as what you expected?

Comment: Nope, see the first post, there are two strings with "v2.0.03", your second is "v2.0 03"

Comment: Ah sorry you're right. I overlooked that. It is corrected now.

Comment: Well I tried your code and I think is the best solution here :)))

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex :

```
([.])(?!\d\d\b|\d\b)|[-_]
```

See [Demo](http://regexr.com/3b7ra)

But note that this will works if your regex engine support different pattern length in look-ahead.

Also note that this will match dots that not followed by 2 digit or 1 digit (using word boundary for refuse of matching `.232`) or one of `[-_]`

Comment: Well works great, but doesn't catch the last dash :)

Comment: @beBoss I'm glad of that ;)

Comment: It won't work with `Welcome.to-RegEx_r.v2.0.03.by.gski.v2.0.03 danner.com!bla-la_12.23-13!`

Comment: Really thanks. But is there a way to match .234 or .3456 I'm just curious, and I'm using jquery

Comment: Voting this one up, nice answer. Would be impressed if it'd work with `la_12.23` instead of `la_122.232`.

Comment: @bjfletcher If you want to apply all scenarios it wouldn't bee a regex task! :)

Comment: @Kasra Thought so too, you sayin' it is impossible? ;)

Comment: @bjfletcher Not impossible but think that you do that what then? :) if you want to create a 100% general answer you need to consider a lot of possibilities! like `v2.0.00003` or maybe `vff.0.d3`,`v2.0.03.3.3` or ...

Answer (score 0):

Try it with
`(?<!v\d(.\d))(?<!v\d)[\.\-_]`
(since many engine do not support quantifiers in lookbehind, I tried that this way
https://regex101.com/r/eH7jE0/1

This pattern includes "v", therefore it may be more robust than without it

Comment: Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds at all.

Comment: True, but the first version of this question didn't have any JavaScript tag.

Comment: sorry my bad about missing tag